# How many wired controllers can be used on an Xbox One X?

Tags: xbox-one

I don't have the Xbox One X yet, but I bought two $30 wired controllers and I wanted to know how many wired controllers can fit on the new Xbox One X console.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I've never had a console before sadly but yah usb ports are very simple so thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like the regular Xbox One, the Xbox One X has [3 USB slots](https://www.windowscentral.com/xbox-one-x-specs). One front-facing, and 2 rear-facing.